Specflow WebAPI Automation : JPath creation for a value string with parenthesis or hyphen
JPath string with value in single quotes is not working for me as the value string has parenthesis or hyphen in it.
For eg.
Jpath =>  "Key1Id": "$.[?(@.key1Id == '{Key1Id}' && @.key1Name == '{Key1Name}' && @.Key2Id == '{Key2Id}')].Key1Id"
In online JPath evaluator, I put values but not getting any response with single quotes:
$.[?(@.key1Name == '7th Edition (AJCC)' && @.key2Name == 'Musculoskeletal - Bone Sarcoma' && @.Key1Id == '75')].Key1Id
So, I added double quotes instead of single quotes:
$.[?(@.key1Name == "7th Edition (AJCC)" && @.key2Name == "Musculoskeletal - Bone Sarcoma" && @.key2Id == "75")].key1Id
This worked for me in online evaluator.
I tried using double quotes with escape characters in Specflow JPath file but not getting any response.
For eg. JPath => "Key1Id": "$.[?(@.Key1Id == \"{Key1Id}\" && @.key2Name == \"{key2Name}\" && @.key2Id == \"{key2Id}\")].key1Id"
Has anyone aware of the such a scenario where JPath value string has parenthesis or hyphen? Please share if we have any solution for this.
Json response:
[
    {
        "key1Id": 5,
        "key1Name": "7th Edition (AJCC)",
        "key2Id": 1,
        "key2Name": "Adrenal Cortical Carcinoma"
    },
    {
        "key1Id": 5,
        "key1Name": "7th Edition (AJCC)",
        "key2Id": 12,
        "key2Name": "Brain - Infratentorial Tumor"
    },
    {
        "key1Id": 5,
        "key1Name": "7th Edition (AJCC)",
        "key2Id": 23,
        "key2Name": "Brain - Supratentorial Tumor"
    },
    {
        "key1Id": 5,
        "key1Name": "7th Edition (AJCC)",
        "key2Id": 34,
        "key2Name": "Breast Cancer"
    }
]


Can you [edit] your question to include all relevant code? The jpath expressions alone are not enough. We need a [repro] before we can answer your question.
